# Support for libraries with same package name is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: android-studio, maven, gradle, repository, jcenter

When I use the Android Studio to build the old project, when gradle sychronizing, it pop out such message, and the package are not pulled from the repository,

WARNING [Project: :app] Support for libraries with same package name is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING [Project: :libraries_res:chrome_res] Support for libraries with same package name is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING [Project: :libraries_res:ui_res] Support for libraries with same package name is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING [Project: :libraries_res:content_res] Support for libraries with same package name is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.086 secs

My repository is Maven and Jcenter

Use many way to pull ,check the jdk , sdk, ndk ,graldle, graldle plugin versions but all are useless

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of package name conflicting with the libraries [or] dependencies defined in your build.gradle file. If the package name is enforced through the build file (build.gradle), try to remove "Package Name" parameter if any. This should automatically create a package name during the runtime.

Furthermore, "enforceUniquePackageName=false" plays a key role here and the enforcement key depends on the structural definition of the library names. So, try to toggle the option between true/false if it's defined in your build file already.